# How to remove 'permission denied' on copying app?

Tags: macos, deployment, ant

I have [copied Mac app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603625/how-to-preserve-exec-file-in-ant-copy-task) using following command -

```
<exec executable="cp">
    <arg line="-R old_folder/bundles my_new_folder"/>
</exec>
```

But for some files I am getting 'Permission Denied' for some files.
How can I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: what kind of files are throwing "Permission Denied" errors? Are they privileged ("`root`" / "`admin`")?

Comment: I am copying jre into my app from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home/jre, for some files it throw PERMISSION DENIED.